# R: ggplot2 & Plotly: Recreating 'reference bands' on bar graphs from Tableau in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am trying to recreate some functionality I use daily in Tableau for R (ggplot2 and plotly). I need to be able to create reference bands and lines similar to the image below. I've figured out how to create the reference lines from the geom_errorbar(). However I can't seem to find a solution for the 'Reference Band'.

If a solution isn't possible in ggplot2 or plotly I would be open to another package, but I need somethign static for Rmarkdown reports and something dynamic for html widgets dashboard.

Below I Have some sample code, I would like to add reference bands of 'High' and 'Low' to the bar graph for each person.

```
library(ggplot2)

#Create Data
Name <- c("Rick","Carl","Daryl","Glenn")
Pos <- c("M","M","D","D")
Load <- c(100,110,90,130)
High <- c(150,160,130,140)
Low <- c(130,145,120,130)
data <- data.frame(Name,Pos,Load,High,Low)
rm(Name,Pos,Load,High,Low)


#create plot
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Name, y = Load)) +
    geom_bar(stat ="identity", width=.4)
```

Could any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Giving us a reproducible example (data and your actual ggplot graph) would make it easear to help you out.

Comment: Thank you, I will.

Answer (score 1):

`geom_rect()` would be a better choise than `geom_errorbar()` because you can reproduce the same image that you posted. Take a look at both [rect](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_rect.html) and [errorbar](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_errorbar.html) documentarion.

The following example could be used in the markdown:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

delta <- 0.5
data <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, vs) %>%
  summarise(xmin = first(cyl) - 1,
            xmax = first(cyl) + 1,
            wt = mean(wt),
            ymin = wt - delta,
            ymax = wt + delta)

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = cyl, y = wt)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax),
            fill = "indianred", alpha = 0.4) + # adds the reference band layer before
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "darkblue", width = 1) + # the bar layer
  facet_wrap(~vs) + theme_classic()
```

[image]

If you wish just one reference band you just have to use the same `ymax` and `ymin` parameters to all the observations.

You will still need more effort in the html version, because `plotly::ggplotly()` is messing it up.

Comment: Okay, I played around with your solution. It makes sense when the  x-axis is continuous. How would I make that work with the y-axis being discrete? I added a data set to the top.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution. I needed to set the xmin and xmax as numeric and then I was able to create the reference bars.

```
library(ggplot2)

#Create Data
NameID <- c("Rick","Carl","Daryl","Glenn")
Pos <- c("M","M","D","D")
Load <- c(100,110,90,130)
High <- c(110,160,130,140)
Low <- c(90,145,120,130)
df <- data.frame(NameID,Pos,Load,High,Low)
rm(NameID,Pos,Load,High,Low)

p <- ggplot()
p <- p + scale_x_discrete()
p <- p + geom_rect(data=df, 
                       aes(xmin = as.numeric(NameID)-.25, 
                           xmax = as.numeric(NameID)+.25, 
                           ymin = Low, 
                           ymax = High),
                       fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2)
p <- p + geom_bar(data = df, aes(x = NameID, y = Load), stat="identity", width = .4)
p
```